# Installing external, unverfied package with Pip 1.5

Tags: python, django, pip, packaging, package-managers

I am trying to install django-admin-tools 0.5.1 using pip 1.5.5 with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I first tried:

```
$ pip install django-admin-tools==0.5.1
Downloading/unpacking django-admin-tools==0.5.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-admin-tools==0.5.1 (from versions: 0.4.0)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-admin-tools==0.5.1
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpd5Tb2I
```

The documentation at `'pip help install'` says:

```
 --allow-external <package>  Allow the installation of externally hosted files
```

Trying with that flag enabled:

```
$ pip install --allow-external django-admin-tools==0.5.1                                                                                                                 
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

That was weird. After a little tinkering, I found that the external package URL was not https ([setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/src/50fd97a834d86a54befc59e7cb24fe3a5e60ccd1/setup.py?at=default)). So I tried with the flag `--allow-unverified`:

```
$ pip install --allow-external --allow-unverified django-admin-tools==0.5.1                                                                                              
Downloading/unpacking django-admin-tools==0.5.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-admin-tools==0.5.1 (from versions: 0.4.0)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-admin-tools==0.5.1
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpoT1_tW
```

Am I using it wrong? How to work around this and install django-admin-tools using pip?

Comment: did you try `pip install django-admin-tools` without giving the version? Or try the easy_install..

Comment: @visakh yes, but that's unrelated. pip 1.5 by default does not support external and unverifiable packages. you need to use flags to be able to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try invoking:

```
pip install django-admin-tools==0.5.1 --allow-external django-admin-tools --allow-unverified django-admin-tools
```

Comment: Thanks. --allow-external is not necessary though.

Answer (score 3):

Both `--allow-unverified` and `--allow-external` take package name as an argument.

```
From pip help install:
--allow-external <package>   Allow the installation of a package even if it
                             is externally hosted
--allow-unverified <package> Allow the installation of a package even if it 
                             is hosted in an insecure and unverifiable way
```

So your usage should be

`pip install <pkg> --allow-unverified <pkg> --allow-external <pkg>`

or the little confusing:

`pip install --allow-unverified <pkg> --allow-external <pkg> <pkg>`

Comment: I still get`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gitlib (from versions: )`when trying to install gitlib.

Comment: @user2284570 perhaps posting a new thread with details would help.

Comment: pip complained about unverified and external.  but when I enable those options, I still get the same message without other indication. There’s nothing to to tell more in a question. If would posted it, it would be downvoted and deleted because it would a very simple problem.

Comment: I won’t post a thread to get it closed without an answer. This can only be answered with a comment on a related question *(and the problem is I’m missing a command line option for sure)*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$ pip install django-admin-tools==0.5.1 --allow-unverified django-admin-tools
```

Related bug report [#1814 - pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1814).